# In Java, how to traverse two lists at the same time?

Tags: java

E.g.

```
for(String str : list1) {
...
}

for(String str : list2) {
...
}
```

suppose we are sure that `list1.size()` equals `list2.size()`, how to traverse these two lists in one `for` statement?

Maybe something like `for(String str1 : list1, str2 : list2)` ?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the lists are of different lengths?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i< list1.size(); i++){
  String str1 = list1.get(i);
  String str2 = list2.get(i);
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: prefer count in place of list1.size() and compute count as Math.min( list1.size(), list2.size()) to be safe.

Comment: You shouldn't use this method when using `LinkedList`s. Each iteration the `get` method will iterate from the beginning of the list to the current element, which leads to O(n²) asymptotic performance. When using linked lists it's highly recommended to use iterators instead.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [iterators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29):

```
Iterator<String> it1 = list1.iterator();
Iterator<String> it2 = list2.iterator();
while(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) { .. }
```

Or:

```
for(Iterator<String> it1 = ... it2..; it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext();) {...}
```

Comment: And I thought nobody has ever run into an infinite collection in Java ;)

Comment: This is a good solution except that the OP wants one `for` statement.

Comment: for (Iterator<String> i1 = one.iterator(), i2 = two.iterator(); i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext();) {...}

Comment: To be complete: add it.next() into the loop and a message if the one iterator has remaining items.

Answer (score 2):

You can't traverse two lists at the same time with the enhanced `for` loop; you'll have to iterate through it with a traditional `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++)
{
    String str1 = list1.get(i);
    String str2 = list2.get(i);
    ...
}
```

Comment: prefer count in place of list1.size() and compute count as Math.min( list1.size(), list2.size()) to be safe.

Comment: True, that's a good way to stay away from an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but the OP stated already that a precondition was that "we are sure that `list1.size()` equals `list2.size()`" already.

Answer (score 1):

Use basic loop

```
for(int index=0; index < list1.size() ; index++){
  list1.get(index);
  list2.get(index);
}
```

Comment: prefer count in place of list1.size() and compute count as Math.min( list1.size(), list2.size()) to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested, this is the solution that will iterate fully thru both lists even if they are not of the same size.

```
int max = Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size());
for(int i=0; i<max; ++i){
    if(list1.size()<i){
        list1.get(i);
    }
    if(list2.size()<i){
        list2.get(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say that both the list are of same size, then you can use "for" loop instead of "for-each" loop. You can use get(int index) method of list to get the value during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;
for(String str1 : list1) {
    str2 = list2.get(index++);
}
```